# zxing invalid barcodes other than qr

Tags: barcode4j

I am using the simple code below and as titled.  How can I print simple Code39 or UPC?  Even code39 of the same data prints unreadable bars that are different per data but do not scan.

Comment: this code
<code>
           try {
                //bitMatrix = qrCodeWriter.encode(sku, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width, height);
                //bitMatrix = qrCodeWriter.encode(sku, BarcodeFormat.CODE_39, width, height);
                bitMatrix = barcode.encode(upc, BarcodeFormat.UPC_A, width, height);
                
            } catch (WriterException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Reorder.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }